# Бесконечный Terrain LOD

Tags: webgl, three.js, алгоритм, javascript, opengl

Кому приходилось создавать террейн с LOD? Сама среда реализации не важна, важен алгоритм, естественно в 3D.

При условии, что данные для тайлов должны подгружаться динамически.
Есть тайлы 5 уровней:

```
1х1,2х2,4х4,8х8,16х16
```

При перемещении камеры перерисовывает тайлы тогда, когда камера переместилась на одну единицу, равную ширине/длине тайла 1х1.

Перерисовывает следующим образом: удаляет тайлы со сцены и добавляет новые уже по новом правилу (позиции).

Из-за этого в этот момент времени (перерисовывания) на долю секунды зависает.
Какие есть другие методы для реализации этого? Вся сложность в том, что данные для террейна подгружаются постепенно, и уже использовать heightMap не получается.